# pandas group by row wise conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'ID':['101','101','101','101','101','102','102','103'],
            'Week':['W01','W02','W03','W07','W08','W01','W02','W01'],
            'Orders':[15,15,10,15,15,5,10,10]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['ID','Week','Orders'])
```

i wanted row by row percentages within groups.

How can i achieve like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `pct_change`

```
df2.groupby('ID').Orders.pct_change()).add(1).fillna(0)
```

I find it wired in my pandas version pct_change can not do with groupby object , so that we need to do with

```
df2['New']=sum(l,[])
df2.New=(df2.New+1).fillna(0)
df2
Out[606]: 
    ID Week  Orders       New
0  101  W01      15  0.000000
1  101  W02      15  1.000000
2  101  W03      10  0.666667
3  101  W07      15  1.500000
4  101  W08      15  1.000000
5  102  W01       5  0.000000
6  102  W02      10  2.000000
7  103  W01      10  0.000000
```

Comment: @anky_91 that is wired I just run in my work environment , it dose not work .. but working in my testing environment .

Answer (score 0):

Carry out a window operation shifting the value by 1 position

```
df2['prev']=df2.groupby(by='ID').Orders.shift(1).fillna(0)
```

Calculate % change individually using apply()

```
df2['pct'] = df2.apply(lambda x : ((x['Orders'] - x['prev']) / x['prev']) if x['prev'] != 0 else 0,axis=1)
```

I am not sure if there is any default pd.pct_change() within a window.

```
    ID  Week    Orders  prev    pct
0   101 W01 15  0.0 0.000000
1   101 W02 15  15.0    0.000000
2   101 W03 10  15.0    -0.333333
3   101 W07 15  10.0    0.500000
4   101 W08 15  15.0    0.000000
5   102 W01 5   0.0 0.000000
6   102 W02 10  5.0 1.000000
7   103 W01 10  0.0 0.000000
```